# How to delete page from sitemap MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, sitemap

I generate `sitemap` with `gadicohen:sitemaps` and I have some pages that live one month. For good seo I need to remove them from the sitemap after they expire. Any idea how to do it ?
[Package](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-sitemaps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you would just need to regenerate your sitemap on a regular basis using a cron job built with (for example) [gadicohen:synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron)

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Update sitmap.xml',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    return parser.text('every 1 day');
  },
  job: function() {
    sitemaps.add('/sitemap.xml', function() {
      ... // define your sitemap
    return;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It will replace previous map ? Or it will just add new item ?

Comment: I believe it will replace the previous sitemap.